# Is thread 0 always the main thread in an iOS crash report?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Is thread 0 always the main thread in an iOS  crash report?  If not how can I determine which thread is the main thread in an ios crash report.  (This is for the cases when you cannot see the thread name in the crash report.)

Comment: It should always be thread 0.  You can also tell by looking at the stack traces: The main thread stack trace should have a call to `main` in it while the other threads should begin with a call to `thread_start` or something similar.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.

[Here is a great read courtesy of Apple on how to decipher the terminology they use in the crash report](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2151/_index.html).